# Cocoa pods: Pod install issue

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoapods

This is the content of my pod file.

```
platform:ios, '5.0'

pod 'AFNetworking', :'~> 1.1.0'
```

When I try $pod install. I m getting following error.

```
 [!] Pod::Executable clone "https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git" "/Users/administrator/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/GitHub/a7f129229d47b74a225e1e2ed0bc604f35d71ac7" --mirror

Cloning into bare repository '/Users/administrator/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/GitHub/a7f129229d47b74a225e1e2ed0bc604f35d71ac7'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git/': Failed connect to github.com:443; Operation timed out
```

It's blocking me to proceed. What is the issue?

Comment: I think the podfile should be `pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.1.0'` without the `:`.Can you try that?

Comment: Even I tried the same following issue arise..[!] Pod::Executable clone "https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git" "/Users/administrator/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/GitHub/a7f129229d47b74a225e1e2ed0bc604f35d71ac7" --mirror

Cloning into bare repository '/Users/administrator/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/GitHub/a7f129229d47b74a225e1e2ed0bc604f35d71ac7'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git/': Failed connect to github.com:443; Operation timed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Old version of AFNetworking. because it have deployment target is 5.0. and the Mac os version is 10.7.

Spec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name     = 'AFNetworking'
  s.version  = '1.1.0'
  s.license  = 'MIT'
  s.summary  = 'A delightful iOS and OS X networking framework.'
  s.homepage = 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking'
  s.authors  = { 'Mattt Thompson' => 'm@mattt.me', 'Scott Raymond' => 'sco@gowalla.com' }
  s.source   = { :git => 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git', :tag => '1.1.0' }
  s.source_files = 'AFNetworking'
  s.requires_arc = true

  **s.ios.deployment_target = '5.0'**
  s.ios.frameworks = 'MobileCoreServices', 'SystemConfiguration'

  **s.osx.deployment_target = '10.7'**
  s.osx.frameworks = 'CoreServices', 'SystemConfiguration'

  s.prefix_header_contents = <<-EOS
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <Availability.h>
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
  #import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
  #import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#else
  #import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
  #import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
#endif
#endif /* __OBJC__*/
EOS
end
```

so should be use update version https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking

Comment: As I mentioned in pod file.

platform:ios, '5.0'. I want it from ios5